# Numerical Limits of writeByte() in Java

Tags: java

The data output stream method writeByte(int), as the name suggests, writes a one byte int over the stream.

What are the limits of this? Is it 256 or is it signed and it's -128 to 127?

Comment: How can I test this without setting up a server?

Comment: The `DataOutputStream` does not require a server. You can wrap it around every `OutputStream`. Use a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`writeByte(int)` invokes `write(int)`. The documentation of `write(int)` says:

> Writes the specified byte (the low eight bits of the argument b) to
>   the underlying output stream.

Therefore it doesn't matter what range of integers the `int` argument lies in. Two arguments that differ by a multiple of `256` will cause that same byte to be written.

One easy way to test this is to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Try this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeByte(-128);
    dos.writeByte(-128 + 256);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()));
}
```

The output is `[-128, -128]` because the same `byte` has been written twice.